# How to change PDF higher version to lower version using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, pdf

I am using Node.js with PDF file. I am working logic that is handle lower version of PDF.

Normally open PDF-> save as->reduced file size pdf  option to save lower version.

I want to add this logic into Node.js program.

How to convert higher version of PDF to lower version of PDF?

Any one assist me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to run an external program from Node.js?

Comment: No.  How to change pdf version using node.js programmatically?

Comment: Then you will need to find a pdf reader and pdf writer for Node.js. Or change the text, e.g. `%PDF-1.7` to, say, `%PDF-1.5` and hope the PDF didn't use any 1.7 features.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem while working with a pdf parser that accepts only the legacy compression up to version `%PDF-1.4` of pdf files. I needed to downgrade the compression of a file saved as version `%PDF-1.7`. That what works for me is [pdf-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-lib?activeTab=readme) package and  `useObjectStreams` option set to `false` when saving the file.

```
const result = await pdfDoc.saveAsBase64({useObjectStreams: false});
```